# column field name not displayed in a query with clickhouse-client | bash

Tags: bash, shell, clickhouse

I'm trying to perform a "SELECT" statement query in a bash script to get display data from clickhouse, is working but not displaying the field name, but if I do it directly from the clickhouse-client it display the column field.

Example in clickhouse-client:

```
ubuntu :) SELECT name FROM persons

Output:
┌─────name─────┐
│    George    │
│    Michael   │
│    Robert    │
 ───────────────
```

but if I do the same in shell is displayed like this:

```
DBQuery="SELECT name FROM persons"
clickhouse-client --query="${DBQuery}"

Output:
George    
Michael
Robert
```

Do you know how can be the output in bash for the output looks like table format?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/cli/) for clickhouse-client? Especially the part on command line options? Anything there stand out as a possible fix?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it putting the flag --format="Pretty"

You can find all the formats in: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#formats